# Encryption algorithms that require more work to decrypt versus encrypt?

Tags: encryption, decryption, performance

Are there any encryption algorithms that require significantly more work to **de**crypt, versus the amount of work required to **en**crypt?

I'm looking for a method of fast encryption, but which will require much more CPU time to decrypt later, as a method of spam prevention (prevent people from decrypting too many files in a short amount of time).

One thing I should mention, is that the encryption key itself will be public knowledge.
I'm not trying to lock anyone out, I just want to force them to work before they can acquire data.

Comment: Symmetric or asymmetric?

Comment: @forest Preferably symmetric, but I'm open to any ideas right now. (Early design stages.)

Comment: This looks like an X/Y problem. What is the thing you're trying to _do_?

Comment: @forest It's not an X/Y problem, but the super-short explanation is I'm building a decentralized distributed file storage system, and I need to discourage people from crawling the entire network and manually building complete hash lookups. Making them have to work for the data, is the perfect method of discouragement, while still allowing people to search normally in smaller volumes.

Comment: It looks like you should be looking for access control and rate control instead of increasing the work factor (which is almost sure to not work as well as you expect).

Comment: @A.Hersean Yeah, unfortunately there is no centralized infrastructure, so standard server-side access control is not generally possible. I need to think outside the box a bit. Proof-of-work is the best decentralized method I'm aware of (i.e. Bitcoin), but I certainly have only little knowledge on this topic.

Comment: Bitcoin should have taught you that proof of work is a bad idea: motivated people will have enough work power, while normal users will be negatively impacted. It will most likely not solve your problem and just make your system use so much power that nobody in their right mind would want to use it.

Comment: @A.Hersean Bah, you make a good point ... hmm, I need to brainstorm more.

Comment: @A.Hersean Upon further reflection, I think I will implement proof-of-work in this manner, but take heed to ensure the average user experience is not negatively impacted - and I'll just accept the fact that a $50,000 mining rig will break it immediately. Therefore it won't be a complete solution, but one step in the right direction. I might need to augment this with other safeguards, but a mild (small) proof-of-work will definitely help to some degree.

Comment: After all answers above I agree with @forest, it is an X/Y problem. If access to these files has some value to the users, they will cooperate. Everyone will post the data that he knows about particular file so that the others benefit from it and save their time.

Comment: @mentallurg Your prediction is generally reasonable. However, with my very short explanation, I don't blame you for misunderstanding the scope a little bit. `If access to these files has some value to the users` Access to individual files is not particularly valuable. But a *complete* hash dictionary of the entire network may be considered somewhat valuable (not hugely). Meanwhile, a _partially complete_ hash dictionary is effectively useless. Also, 99% of users won't care about this, it's just the 1% of abusers I need to keep at bay. Everyone on the planet would have to cooperate to beat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the encryption key is public knowledge, one simple method is to encrypt using a standard symmetric algorithm (such as AES), but randomize a portion of the encryption key.

For example, if you use AES-256, and the encryption key is published, but each individual encrypted file has 12 bits of the key overwritten with a random value (which is never saved or stored anywhere), so decrypting the file will require the decrypting device to brute-force the final 12 bits of the key.

The number of bits randomized, can be adjusted based on how quickly people are able to crack it, to hit whatever sweet-spot of required work you are looking for.

***IMPORTANT:***
It should be noted, as [A. Hersean pointed out in the comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87480/encryption-algorithms-that-require-more-work-to-decrypt-versus-encrypt?noredirect=1#comment192000_87480), that this method may have significant negative side effects:

> ... proof-of-work is a bad idea: motivated people will have enough work power, while normal users will be negatively impacted. It will most likely not solve your problem and just make your system use so much power that nobody would want to use it.

Comment: Are you playing a game with your users? What the hell a normal user will want to this.

Comment: @kelalaka lol it's just a proof-of-work spam prevention methodology. If I design it well, the benefits will greatly outweigh the end-user costs.

Comment: After users find out passwords for particular files, they would post passwords on some external web resource, so that the others benefit from it. Thus you will not slow your users down.

Comment: @mentallurg `they would post passwords on some external web resource, so that the others benefit from it` This would require universal cooperation from every single global user, and would provide no benefit with less than ~95% of users actively participating in the "password posting." (Even with 100% participation, the "benefit" is pretty minor.) As I mentioned in the main question comments, this work requirement is clearly not a complete solution, but just one layer of defense. Without additional safeguards alongside it, this probably won't provide the level of protection I'm looking for.